# Get Popup window After page change

Tags: javascript

Have a flash player that pops out into a separate popup browser window. And on the source page the flash player just displays a message that it is currently popped out.

Now if the user navigates away from the source page (to another page on the same domain) how do i get a reference to the popup or just detect if its open (using javascript on the new page)?

Comment: you can write the script at the bottom of new page to open popup after the new page is loaded

Comment: That would refresh the popup window if it was already loaded, the popup window contains a audio player so making reload would cause breaks in the playing of music. Facebook does this somehow with their popout chat, after leaving their site, the chat stays operational, and doesnt reload when coming back to their site and it shows that the chat is popped out at the bottom of their page. So was hoping for something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. Had to have a javascript timer in the popped out window that trys to execute a function in the parent window that if exists will simply hide the player.

example

Popout window script

```
<script>
    if(window.opener!=null)
        setTimeout("popCheck();",2000);

    function popCheck()
    {
        //Use try catch to prevent premission denied msgs in 
        //case parent window is on different domain
        try
        {
            window.opener.setPoppedOut();
        }
        catch(e)
        {
        }
        //Check Every 2 seconds
        setTimeout("popCheck();",2000);
    }

    window.onbeforeunload = function()
    {
        //Used to facilitate popin on window close
        if(window.opener!=null)
        {
            try
            {
                window.opener.setPoppedIn();
            }
            catch(e)
            {
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Parent window script

```
<script>
    //Save the previous contents so that we can restore them later.
    window.popoutContent = document.getElementById("popoutContent").innerHTML;

    function setPoppedOut()
    {
        document.getElementById("popoutContent").innerHTML = "Player is Popped Out";
    }
    function setPoppedIn()
    {
        document.getElementById("popoutContent").innerHTML = window.popoutContent;
    }
</script>
```